# How to get BITMAPINFOHEADER from OpenCV image?

Tags: c#, winapi, bitmap, marshalling, emgucv

I have to use 3rd party native API that takes pointer to [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) structure and pointer to bitmap data as parameters.

> `static Image load ( IntPtr bi, IntPtr img, string name )`
>
> constructs a image representation from the specified bitmap image in
>   memory. The bi pointer points to a BITMAPINFOHEARER followed by an
>   optional color table. The existence of a colortable depends on the
>   image type. The Byte pointer has to point to bitmap data as described
>   by the bitmap information.

**How do I get pointer to the structure representing uncompressed 24bit RGB bitmap with specified size in C#?**

I have downloaded the BITMAPINFOHEADER stucture C# decalaration from here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/BITMAPINFOHEADER.html

I'm actually working with EmguCV image class and I tried to get the BITMAPINFOHEARER describing the image from [`Image<Rgb, byte>`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm).

```
var image = new Image<Rgb, byte>(@"myImage.bmp");

//1. create BITMAPINFOHEADER instance
var bitmapInfoHeader = new BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    biSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)), //40
    biWidth = image.Width, //4096
    biHeight = image.Height, //4096
    biPlanes = 1,
    biBitCount =24,
    biCompression = BitmapCompressionMode.BI_RGB,
    biSizeImage = (uint)image.Bytes.Length,
};

//2. get pointer to the data
IntPtr ptrData;
fixed (byte* pData = image.Data)
    ptrData = (IntPtr)pData;

//3. get pointer to the BitmapInfoHeader:
int iSizeOfBih = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
IntPtr ptrBih = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(iSizeOfBih);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(bih, ptrBih, false);

fixed (byte* pData = image.Bytes)
{
   var frImage = Bmp.load(pBitmapInfoHeader, (IntPtr)pData, "Frame");
   var faces = faceTracker.processFrame(frImage);
}
```

Although this compiles and runs without exception, it does not load the image correctly (i'm not able to process is later using facetracker.When I used another method to load image from file the facetracker worked)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `BitmapCompressionMode.BI_RGB`.

Comment: `biSize` is not the size of the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not load the image correctly" ? This isn't helpful at all.

Comment: @ElderBug: I use the 3rd party API FaceTracker. If I use another overload of the method, that takes filename, it finds face. If I use this method it doesn't.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image ? Usually, images described by `BITMAPINFOHEADER` have row padding to 4 bytes, which means that there are additional dummy bytes if the width isn't a multiple of 4. If `load` expect row padding and it isn't present, it won't work.

Comment: @ElderBug: I have resized the image to 4096*4096 and changed `biSize`

Comment: It seems `Image` is actually row padded, so the size doesn't matter. Another point, all your usage of `ptrData` should be inside the `fixed` scope. Also, try with `biHeight = -image.Height`.

Comment: setting biHeight = -image.Height fixed it! Write is as answer and I will accept it. Could you also explain why the negative Height in the answer. Why height but not width? Also some links regarding the padding would be helpful. The size actually does matter. When I use another imageSize, e.g 4097*4097 it does not work.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation to which you linked?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True, I have not read the C++ documentation carefully. Shame on me. But I still don't know much about the padding yet and for other readers it should be mentioned in the answer. maybe the have not read or understood the documentation as well.

Comment: With 4097*4097, what if you use `biSizeImage = 0` ? [This page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/8eaaf685-939e-9365-2bd9-22ef02c39b20.htm) indicates that `Image` use padding (in remarks), so it shouldn't be a problem. It could be that `load` actually don't support padding, but that would be strange. If it really is the case, the only solution is to make a copy, row by row, into a byte array that is exactly 4097*4097.

Comment: Actually I don't think that the question should be answered. Where in the question is the information needed to answer? Where can we learn that your DIB is top-down? I think the question should be closed as off topic FWIW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not wrong, but then you would have to close at least a million of questions on SO (good luck). The problem is that SO is intentionally designed to reject these type of questions, but still the best place to ask them. IMO, this paradox is the worst thing on SO that needs to be addressed, but the staff is really stubborn about this.

Comment: @Elderbug I personally largely agree with the rules here. This question is easily fixed with an MCVE and perhaps some images.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: First off all, I didn't new anything about DIB so it couldn't be n the question. Second, its given by the open cv image class. In the question is everything to reproduce the problem, imho. Maybe I should rename the title to "How to get BITMAPINFOHEADER from OpenCV image?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think the rules are wrong, it's just that they ignore the fact that despite being designed for Q/A, SO is also largely used for debugging. If the questioners were able to produce an MCVE, most of them wouldn't need to ask in the first place. The problem is that the policy of SO is to spit on their faces instead of addressing the global problem (provide tools for these questions). Anyway, maybe some day I will post my solution ideas on meta, but I'm pretty sure it will be rejected.

Comment: @Liero No, there is absolutely not everything needed to recreate the issue.

Comment: @ElderBug You make a good point that the poor level of many askers' debugging skills is the root cause of questions like this one. I'm not sure what the solution is. What I see though is a chronic shortage of programmers that understand the basic techniques of debugging. The best questions are invariably from people that have those skills at hand and so are able to present clear and isolated problems. My belief is that  if we found a way to teach debugging rather than do the debugging, the world would be better for it.

Comment: @Liero About your question, I don't think the points made here apply. I think it is mostly fine. It could use some additional code (like the call to `load`), but it turns out be be answerable as is, so it can be forgiven. The problem is that too many times the problem is in the code not shown.

Comment: I don't want to ask poor question next time, but I still don't know what I did wrong, given my knowledge at that time, except maybe the title - The problem was not the pointer as stated in the title but the values of the structure.
I have added the usage of load method. Originally I have skipped it, because it is not publicly available api and as it turned out it was not needed anyway.

Comment: Well, as I said I think it was mostly fine. To do better : include as much involved code as you can. Even if it is useless in your case, it permits to see that you didn't do something stupid somewhere (it can always happen). Describe the actual problem with more details (what you expected and what you got instead). Here you couldn't see much, but say it anyway; the viewers don't know. Also include any debugging you did, if any (it's better to have some, even if just to motivate the viewers; here, you could check with the debugger that `pData` and `ptrBih` pointed to expected data).

Comment: @ElderBug FWIW, how did you know that the data was top-down?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because it is more common for memory representation. Files may be bottom-up, but here it is a ready-to-use bitmap in memory, so it is much more convenient and conventional to have it top-down. Strictly speaking, it was just an educated guess.

Comment: @ElderBug An image would have made that obvious.  It would have been upside down.  At that point almost anyone with winapi experience would have been able to answer.  A statement as to what was wrong with the image would have made it clear. The entire problem statement in the question was "it does not load the image correctly". Personally I think we should not encourage askers to ask that way. I don't think that helps anyone, least of all them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The actual problem was indeed not well explained. But from OP's point of view, it was probably all he had. Since the 3rd party lib is for face tracking, maybe there is no way to display the image, and displaying the image with the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` would need decent knowledge of WinAPI (and more interops). So all he knew was that the facetracking didn't work, and deduced it was because of `load` and its parameters, and he was right. I still agree that he should have at least added that he actually didn't know more.

Comment: @ElderBug: I think you deserve the credits for answering the question, despite the poor quality.  Will you write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recap from the comments**

Most of the info for how to fill `BITMAPINFOHEADER` can be found on the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx).

Some points that should be corrected :
`biSize` should be filled with the size of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. This field is here because the struct can be a more complete version like `BITMAPV5HEADER`, so it may work if set incorrectly higher, but it's obviously not recommended.
`biCompression` should be set to `BI_RGB`. `BI_BITFIELDS` is not documented as valid for 24-bit mode.
`biHeight` should be set to be negative if the image is top-down, which is likely the case for a memory representation like in your case. If not, the image may be loaded upside down.
`biSizeImage` seems to be set correctly, but since it is allowed to fill it with 0 in `BI_RGB` mode, it may prevent errors to do so.
Also, all the uses of the pinned pointer (with `fixed`) should be done inside the `fixed` scope. If it is used outside, there is no guarantee that the array won't be moved elsewhere.

About the dimensions, the `Image` class seems to use row padding, that is, filling the rows with additional bytes if their width isn't a multiple of 4 bytes. Bitmaps described by `BITMAPINFOHEADER` should also have this property, so `load` could be expected to work for all dimensions, but if `load` actually don't support row padding, it may be needed to copy the image to an array that have the exact dimensions. Another solution is to use 32-bit mode everywhere (and it may also increase performances).